# How do I Configure 'org-latex-classes in .emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I use emacs org-mode for keeping track of notes and todos. Sometimes I wish to export notes as a latex file, using the official company style. To get the correct heading styles I run the following elisp:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
              '("report"
                "\\documentclass{report}"
                ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
                ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))
              )
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in .emacs. I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable org-latex-classes)
  (member (quote ("report" "\\documentclass{report}" ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}") ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}") ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}") ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))) org-latex-classes)
  (if (member (quote ("report" "\\documentclass{report}" ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}") ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}") ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}") ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))) org-latex-classes) org-latex-classes (setq org-latex-classes (cons (quote ("report" "\\documentclass{report}" ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}") ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}") ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}") ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))) org-latex-classes)))
  eval((if (member (quote ("report" "\\documentclass{report}" ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}") ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}") ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}") ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))) org-latex-classes) org-latex-classes (setq org-latex-classes (cons (quote ("report" "\\documentclass{report}" ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}") ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}") ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}") ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))) org-latex-classes))) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

The command only works if I have run org-export-dispatch to export to PDF before running add-to-list.

I'm kind of a beginner at elisp and configuring Emacs, and even more of a beginner at using Latex. So if someone could tell me how to get the command to work in .emacs I would be very grateful. I'm guessing the list has not been created yet when .emacs is loaded, but I'm at a loss about how to make this work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the following:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex
   (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
                '("report"
                  "\\documentclass{report}"
                  ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
                  ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                  ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                  ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))))
```

This adjusts the variable as soon as the ox-latex package is loaded.

Answer (score 5):

The list `org-latex-classes` is defined in `ox-latex.el`, so you need to insert `(require 'ox-latex)` in your `.emacs` before adding to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked! For the record, how am I supposed to know these things, or find them out?

Comment: No no no. There's no reason to slow down your Emacs startup by loading all of org on startup.